# C Program Crashing when Reallocing One Element Larger (2x)

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am a beginner to C and am trying to learn dynamic memory allocation in the simplest way - I have a program that manages student records and I have a few problems with it that I cannot for the life of me figure out even after hours and hours of googleing/stackoverflowing -- Here is what this program is to accomplish:

- Take in student records
- Add and Delete Records ( THESE ARE THE COMMANDS THAT DO NOT WORK)
- Sort student records
- Find a few extra values from these records

Here is what happens to create this error as found in GDB debugger (the problem comes with the addRecord function and the freeMemory function):

```
    *** Error in `/home/a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 
    0x0000000000c42060 ***                                                        
    Aborted
```

And when compiled with GCC and ran outside of the GDB debugger it will just seg fault.

This only happens when I do these set of options in the program:

1) ADD A RECORD

2) DELETE A RECORD

3) ADD A RECORD ( THEN CRASHES )

or

1) ADD A RECORD

2) ADD A RECORD ( THEN CRASHES )

I'm not sure whats causing this and I have no idea how to fix it, can anyone help direct me in the right direction? I've tried adding a free after the realloc success in the freeMemory function but to no avail this then causes the program to crash upon deletion of an added record.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Declare functions:
void printMenu();
void printRecords(char** fn, char** ln, float* s);
void addRecord(char** fn, char** ln, float* s);
void deleteRecord(char** fn, char** ln, float* s);
int freeMemory(char** fn, char** ln, float* s, char* n, int matches);
int findName(char** ln,char* n);


static int records; // global records variable

int main(){
    int i, j;
    int choice;
    int option = -1;

    printf("WELCOME TO THE STUDENT RECORD MANAGER 100 V 1.0! \n");
    printf("Please indicate the number of student records you want to enter (min 5, max 15): \n");
    scanf("%d",&records);

    if(records < 5 || records > 15){
        printf("You must enter more than five and less than 15... terminating. \n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Declare arrays
    char** firstNames;
    char** lastNames;
    float* scores;

    // Declare variables
    char* search = malloc(64);

    firstNames  =   malloc(records*sizeof(*firstNames));
    lastNames   =   malloc(records*sizeof(*lastNames));
    scores      =   malloc(records*sizeof(float));


    printf("Please enter the records now (ex. firstName lastName score ENTER):\n");
    // Gather Records
    for(i = 0; i < records; i ++){
        printf("%d ",i+1);
        firstNames[i] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char));
        lastNames[i] = malloc(254 * sizeof(char));
        //scores[i] = malloc(sizeof(float));
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstNames[i], lastNames[i], &scores[i]);
    }

    // Generate menu and do actions
    do{
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printRecords(firstNames, lastNames, scores);
                break;
            case 2:
                addRecord(firstNames, lastNames, scores);
                break;
            case 3:
                deleteRecord(firstNames, lastNames, scores);
                break;
            case 0:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    while(1);
    return 0;
}

// Print user menu
void printMenu(){
    printf("\tMain Menu\t\n"
        "============================\n"
        " > Print records (press 1) \n"
        " > Add a new record (press 2) \n"
        " > Delete a record (press 3) \n"
        " > Exit the program (press 0)\n"
        "============================\n"
        "Please select an option: ");
}

// Print all user records
void printRecords(char** fn, char** ln, float* s){
    int i;
    printf("THERE ARE %d RECORDS \n",records);
    for(i=0;i<records;i++)
        printf("(%d) First name: %s | Last name: %s | Score: %0.2f \n",i,fn[i],ln[i],s[i]); // will start at the first item and go i amount in the index
}

// Add user record
void addRecord(char** fn, char**ln, float* s){
    char** tempPtr;
    float* tempFPtr;
    printf("Please input the values that you'd like to add (ex. firstName lastName score ENTER): \n");
    if(records+1 < 15){ // if the array is not larger than maximum value when we make it larger

        // lets reallocate the arrays
        tempPtr = realloc(fn, (records+1)*sizeof(*fn));
        if(tempPtr){
            printf("ALLOCATION successfully");
            fn = tempPtr;
        }
        else{
            printf("FAILED");
            // Realloc Failed
        }
        tempPtr = realloc(ln, (records+1)*sizeof(*ln));
        if(tempPtr){
            printf("ALLOCATION successfully");
            ln = tempPtr;
        }
        else{
            printf("FAILED");
            // Realloc Failed
        }
        /*tempFPtr = realloc(s, records+1*sizeof(float));
        if(tempFPtr){
            s = tempFPtr;
        }*/
        printf("There are now %d items.. \n", records);
        fn[records] = malloc(64); // in the LAST value of all arrays
        ln[records] = malloc(64);
        scanf("%s %s %f",fn[records], ln[records], &s[records]);
        printf("(%d) > ADDED -> First name: %s | Last name: %s | Score: %0.2f \n",records,fn[records],ln[records],s[records]);
        int i;
        records++; // increment by one
        printf("There are now %d items.. \n", records);
        printf(" > Record successfully added.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf(" > You have hit the max amount of records allowed for this program (15).\n");
    }

}

// Delete all instances of user record by (last Name)
void deleteRecord(char** fn, char**ln, float* s){
    char* lastName = malloc(32 * sizeof(char*));
    printf("What is the last name of the student you would like to delete? \n");
    scanf("%s", lastName);

    // searching for that record
    int matches = findName(ln, lastName);
    if(matches && records-matches > 4){ // this means it doesn't go below minimum 5
        if(freeMemory(fn, ln, s, lastName, matches)){
            printf(" > Record successfully deleted.\n");
            free(lastName);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf(" > Either no matches were found or deleting this value would put the number of records at less than 5. \n");
    }

}

// Extension of deleteRecord that does duplication to push 'delete' lastName to the end, then reallocates array to cut it off the end
int freeMemory(char** fn, char** ln, float* s, char* n, int matches){
    int i,j;

    /* LOGIC:
        - REALLOCATE ARRAY BY X LESS SIZE AFTER PUSHING THE VALUES TO BE REMOVED TO THE END
        - NEED TO DO THIS FOR THREE ARRAYS
        - TO REMOVE:
            - RUN THROUGH X AMOUNT OF TIMES PUSHING EACH SPECIFIC REMOVAL VALUE (IE) 1st found match
            - TO THE END
            SHIFT
                - FOUND 1st MATCH
                - MATCH = MATCH + 1
                - MATCH + ! = MATCH + 2
                - ETC UNTIL YOU HAVE A DUPLICATE AT THE END, THEN REALLOCATE BY 1 LESS
    */
    char** tempPtr = NULL;
    float* tempFPtr = NULL;
    for(i=0;i<matches;i++){ // gonna go through as many times as matches
        int match = 0;
        // let's make sure the name isn't on the end of the array before we do all this junk
        if(strcmp(n,*(ln+records-1)) == 0){
            printf("FN");
            tempPtr = realloc(fn, (records-1)*sizeof(*fn));
            if(tempPtr){
                fn = tempPtr;
                printf("FN PASSED");
                //free(fn[records]);
            }
            else{
                // Realloc Failed
                printf("FN FAILED");
            }
            printf("LN");
            tempPtr = realloc(ln, (records-1)*sizeof(*ln));
            if(tempPtr){
                ln = tempPtr;
                printf("LN PASSED");
                //free(ln[records]);
            }
            else{
                printf("LN FAILED");
                // Realloc Failed
            }

            records--;
        }
        else{
            // lets find the first match by going through each last name
            for(j=0;j<records-1;j++){
                // Lets find first match
                if(strcmp(n,ln[j]) == 0){ // accessing index
                    // lets start copying
                    *(ln+j) = *(ln+j+1);
                    *(fn+j) = *(fn+j+1);
                    *(s+j)  = *(s+j+1);
                    match = 1;
                }
                else if(match){
                    // already copied first val so lets start copying the rest until we get to the end.
                    *(ln+j) = *(ln+j+1);
                    *(fn+j) = *(fn+j+1);
                    *(s+j)  = *(s+j+1);
                }

            }
            printf("FN");
            tempPtr = realloc(fn, (records-1)*sizeof(*fn));
            if(tempPtr){
                fn = tempPtr;
                printf("FN PASSED");
                //free(fn[records]);
            }
            else{
                // Realloc Failed
                printf("FN FAILED");
            }
            printf("LN");
            tempPtr = realloc(ln, (records-1)*sizeof(*ln));
            if(tempPtr){
                ln = tempPtr;
                printf("LN PASSED");
                //free(ln[records]);
            }
            else{
                printf("LN FAILED");
                // Realloc Failed
            }

            /*tempFPtr = realloc(s, records-1*sizeof(float));
            if(tempFPtr){
                s = tempFPtr;
                printf("S PASSED");
            }
            else{
                printf("s FAILED ");
            }*/

            records--;
            match = 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Finds how many instances of a last name are present
int findName(char** ln,char* n){
    int i, counter=0;

    for(i=0;i<records-1;i++){
        if(strcmp(n,*(ln+i)) == 0){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't like debugging this huge code. Please try and create a [mcve].

Comment: @FelixPalmen I have edited it to include only what is required

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger - it could (WILL) narrow the problem down

Comment: So if realloc fails, you just return the original pointer without flagging as an error?  Seems sketchy.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - I concur

Comment: I have removed that portion of the code and taken the user belows advice, now after adding a value and then printing it will print the first value as random values for first and last name and then seg fault. Any ideas?

Comment: @tidwellxyz - Did you write a lot of code and then compiled it - hoping it would work? Or did you write a few lines of code, compile and check?

Comment: @EdHeal I wrote a few lines of code, compiled and then checked. I put it in the GDB Debugger aswell. you can find my updated code above with said changes.

Comment: For more info, after you enter initial data, does it print fine before you try to add or delete records?  Telling to print 1st time through works ok?

Comment: Yes! 1st print works fine. @MichaelDorgan

Comment: Ugh - after you reallocate your arrays, alloc the strings to 64 size instead of original 254.  Also, I see no re-alloc of the scores.  That will cause an array overwrite on the float array. (commented out code I think....)  That array also needs to be passed in as a double pointer if you are changing it.

Comment: I've done both of your suggestions and I'm still getting the print issue. Thank you for your help. @MichaelDorgan

Comment: Another major problem is that the result of `realloc` is assigned to a local variable in a function

Comment: I solved it myself due to @M.M 's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was because I was not using triple pointers to it was not addressing the original variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printMenu();
void printRecords(char** fn, char** ln, double* s);
void addRecord(char ***fn, char ***ln, double **s);
void addString(char ***strArray, char* str);
void addDouble(double** dubArray, double dub);
void deleteRecord(char*** fn, char*** ln, double** s);
void removeString(char ***strArray);
void removeDouble(double** dubArray);
int findName(char** ln,char* n);

int records;
int counter;

int main(){
    records = 0;
    counter = 1;

    int initRecords = 0;
    int choice,i;
    char **fn; // first Names
    char **ln; // last Names
    double *s; // score

    printf("=  =\n"
           "Please enter how many value"
           "s you would like to initall"
           "y enter [min 5, max 15]: ");
    scanf("%d", &initRecords);
    if(initRecords < 5 || initRecords > 15)
        return 0;

    // allocate memory
    fn = malloc(0); // will reallocate later
    ln = malloc(0);
    s =  malloc(0);

    printf("Please enter the value (firstName lastName score ENTER): \n");
    for(i = 0;i<(initRecords);i++){
        addRecord(&fn, &ln, &s);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("Records added... \n");
    do{
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printRecords(fn, ln, s);
                break;
            case 2:
                addRecord(&fn,&ln,&s);
                printf("> Record added. \n");
                break;
            case 3:
                deleteRecord(&fn, &ln, &s);
                printf("> Record deleted. \n");
                break;
            case 0:
                return 0;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    while(1);
}

// Print user menu
void printMenu(){
    printf("\tMain Menu\t\n"
        "============================\n"
        " > Print records (press 1) \n"
        " > Add a new record (press 2) \n"
        " > Delete a record (press 3) \n"
        "============================\n"
        "Please select an option: ");
}

// Print all user records
void printRecords(char** fn, char** ln, double* s){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<records;i++)
        printf("(%d) First name: %s | Last name: %s | Score: %0.2lf \n",i+1,fn[i],ln[i],s[i]); // will start at the first item and go i amount in the index
}


void addRecord(char*** fn, char*** ln, double** s){
    // gather value

    char* fname = malloc(64);
    char* lname = malloc(64);
    double score;
    records++;

    printf("%d) ", (counter));
    scanf("%s %s %lf",fname, lname, &score);

    addString(fn, fname);
    addString(ln, fname);
    addDouble(s, score);
}

void addString(char*** strArray, char* str){
    // realloc array one larger
    *strArray = realloc(*strArray, (records) * sizeof(char*));

    // set pointer equal
    (*strArray)[records-1] = str;

}

void addDouble(double** dubArray, double dub){
    // realloc array one larger
    *dubArray = realloc(*dubArray, (records) * sizeof(double));

    // set pointer equal
    (*dubArray)[records-1] = dub;
}

void deleteRecord(char*** fn, char*** ln, double** s){
    //This part gets the name
    int i, j;
    char *name = malloc(64);
    printf("Please enter the last name of the record(s) you'd like to delete: ");
    scanf("%s",name);

    while(findName(*ln, name) != 0){
        for(i = 0;i<records && strcmp(name,(*ln)[i]) != 0;i++);
        records--;
        //free((*ln)[i]);
        //free((*fn)[i]);
        for(i=i; i < records-1; i++){
            (*ln)[i] = (*ln)[i+1];
            (*fn)[i] = (*fn)[i+1];
            (*s)[i] = (*s)[i+1];
        }
        removeString(fn);
        removeString(ln);
        removeDouble(s);
    }

}
void removeString(char ***strArray){
    *strArray = realloc(*strArray, (records) * sizeof(char*));

}
void removeDouble(double** dubArray){
    *dubArray = realloc(*dubArray, (records) * sizeof(double));
}

// Finds how many instances of a last name are present
int findName(char** ln,char* n){
    int i, counter=0;

    for(i=0;i<records-1;i++){
        if(strcmp(n,*(ln+i)) == 0){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error appears to be in your function `addRecord`. You have the expression

```
tempPtr = safe_trim(ln, records+1*sizeof(*ln));
```

Which is giving a size of `records + (sizeof (*ln))` because of [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Multiplication comes before addition. The line should be changed to:

```
tempPtr = safe_trim(ln, (records + 1) * sizeof(*ln));
```

Also because `safe_trim` always return a valid pointer, either the original or the resized, this check

```
tempPtr = safe_trim(fn, records+1*sizeof(*fn));
if(tempPtr){
    printf("ALLOCATION successfully");
    fn = tempPtr;
}
else{
    printf("FAILED");
    // Realloc Failed
}
```

will never follow the `else` branch and won't handle allocation failures. Replacing calls to `safe_trim` with `realloc` shouldn't have any affect on the program except to allow detecting allocation failures.

Comment: I can now add two but it segfaults when trying to print them.

Comment: Outputs like this:

        (1) First name: `�j | Last name:  | Score: 99.00   
                                                                                     
        ...        (other values)                                                                
   
         Segmentation fault

Comment: It also doesn't add them to the array, it still only shows 5 values.

Comment: @tidwellxyz in your printRecords function the arguments to printf are formatted `*(fn + i)`, that only increments the pointer by one byte though and it should be incremented the width of one pointer. The most appropriate way to accomplish that would be `fn[i]`

Comment: for some reason it prints the first value of the array with jumbled up values.. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Time for a new question, or run the debugger.

Comment: @Joel You can find the code I have changed it to in the edit above. It is now working when I add multiple values but it wont print them correctly.

Comment: @tidwellxyz The `malloc` and `realloc` for scores should still be present since that's a dynamically allocated array. Other than that it might be helpful to change the main so instead of relying on user input  it's hardcoded or it just makes calls to `addRecord`, `deleteRecord`, and `printRecords` to validate those functions